# Show Python variable in HTML with Bottle

Tags: python, html, bottle

I'm switching from flask to bottle, I need to display the SSID on my web page.

My flask script was:

Python:

```
return render_template('home.html', form=form, ssid=ssid)
```

HTML:

```
<p>Device name: {{ ssid }}</p>
```

I cannot find how to do that in bottle.

Answer (score 2):

Using template function:

```py
from bottle import template

return template('home.html', ssid=ssid)
```